# Toggle between two commands in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would like to use a simple bash script to toggle on/off of the touchpad of my laptop. I know that I can use
`synclient Touchpadoff=1`
to turn off the touchpad and use
`synclient Touchpadoff=0`
to turn it on. But is there any way to toggle between these two commands (i.e., if the touchpad is off, then turn it on, and vice versa)?

Thanks!

Comment: a function wrapper around `case ${tp_off:=0} in 1 ) tp_off=0 ;; 0 ) tp_off=1 ;; esac ; synclient Touchpadoff=${tp_off}` might be helpful. Good luck.

Comment: You could create an environment variable to check the state

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doing `synclient -l`, you can see the line

```
    TouchpadOff          = 0
```

(or =1)
You then just have to grep this value and call `synclient Touchpadoff=` with the other value.
For instance in a script `toggleTouchpad.sh`, you can have

```
#!/bin/bash
synclient TouchpadOff=$(synclient -l | awk '/TouchpadOff/{print !strtonum($3)}')
```

the `awk` command will print the "opposite" of the third field (`=` is the second), so if it's 1 it will print 0, if it's 0 it will print 1.

Comment: it's quite good asnwer.  i don't have synclient on my machine so i didn't know that -l return only keys or keys with values. :)

Comment: Don't think you need the `strtonum`.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know `synclient -l`. I know nothing about awk, but it says `awk: line 2: function strtonum never defined`. Anyway, I end up writing my own script in OCaml.

Comment: For those of you dealing with "strtonum never defined" error, you can just remove that. I got that error, but the script worked fine for me without converting like that.

Answer (score 0):

not very good, but easy to implement solution is to save in /tmp/touch.state actual state of touchpad.
If it's '0' - enable touchpad and store '1' in file and vice versa